# How to set props type of "a useState function"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to set props type of "a React useState function"

// ParentComponent.tsx

```js
import { useState } from "react"
import ChildComponent "./ChildComponent"

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState<boolean>(false)
  return <ChildComponent setPrompt={setPrompt}/>
}
```

// ChildComponent.tsx

```js
interface ChildComponentProps {
  setPrompt: Function // ✅ WORKED but inaccurate!
  setPrompt: (value: boolean) => void // kinda WORKED thanks @acemarke!
  setPrompt: typeof React.useState //  DOESNT WORK!!!
}

const ChildComponent = (props: ChildComponentProps) => {
  return <button onClick={() => props.setPrompt(false)}>Button</button>
}
```

Comment: `ReturnType<typeof React.useState>>[1]`?

Comment: Or, probably (and more readably): `(v:boolean) => void`

Comment: BTW, If you want to know the type of a specific variable/object, you can just hover over it, and IDE will show the type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over `setPrompt` in your code editor you should see the type:

```
Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
```

Those types come from inside React. So you either want to import them:

```
import type { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react'

Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
```

Or just use them from the `React` namespace.

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
```

WHich makes `ChildComponentProps` something like:

```
interface ChildComponentProps {
  setPrompt: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>
}
```

[Playground with no type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-beta#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxJwC+cAZlBCHAERSoYsBQXaEAdoXgAFFO34wAwk0j8kEuAF44ACgCUSgHy4ucOH0HwA2mEbgscYjGFmwMALpKCxMhSQAeAEYQIAG1T8mip0KL7Earpw7DD4UPxw7pIAFsC+ACbS4ALy8FY2MjCKOHm2MNQA9Jpc1DzAEkhQIWhUyakZMtkS+WCEOnolBQBcyOgwAHQAIsCEYBRoSe4jGGMkSDCulACCGMACXj7+KIFVNbwCQnCt6ZmyOU4qphA9g5cp1x1yXYw9GoraOJForF4l58DAYAI4AJJL5gGgANZFdRaOCPHpjAbmYKhcLUTQAITBEP47nKniJAhOQA)

Comment: Thanks. I think you answered my question. I made up my mind and really think this kind of hard to read. `(value :boolean) => void` is a better choice.

Comment: Well that's not the right type. React state setters can also take a function that provides the current state as an argument `setState(prev => ({ ...prev, someProp: true })`. So you can call it with a value for the new state, or a function that returns the new state. This makes the actual type a lot more complicated. If you don't like it you could make a type alias: `type ReactStateSetter<T> = React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<T>>`. [See playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8oZPW)

Comment: Your answer is technically true though. In my case, it worked (for just setting state of true/false). Plus, it adds flexibility and convenience to my code.

After asking the question, I just don't think of forcing someone to pass the a `setState` receives a function as an argument or a value any more.

Comment: Well then `(value: boolean) => void` should work fine, if you don't all the other features of a state setter function.